# Adding cname without putting the subdomain

Tags: subdomain, cname-record

I want to point www.example.com or example.com to abc.example2.com.

In my cname zone settings for example.com, I have added a cname as follows:

name:  www.example.com
type:  cname
value: abc.example2.com

and so when I visit www.example.com it shows me the content of abc.example2.com which is absolutely correct. But when I visit example.com (without www or any other sub domain), it's not working. I even tried adding a record set as follows:

name:  example.com
type:  cname
value: abc.example2.com

But it gives me the following errors in 2 different DNS hosting websites:
Route 53

```
RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.com. is not permitted at apex in zone example.com.
```

DYNDNS

```
CNAME cannot be created with label that is equal to zone name or in use for another record type.
```

Now, how can I achieve when visiting example.com it should show the content of abc.example2.com ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a label (name) is a CNAME, no other records are allowed for it. so you can't have something like:

```
www.example.com  A     1.2.3.4
www.example.com  CNAME test.example.com.
```

The effect of this, is that you can *never* have a CNAME for the bare example.com domain, as there are *always* other records for it: at least the SOA record and one or more NS records and usually one or more MX records. So this must be an A record instead.

What I usually do is go the other way around: make www.example.com a CNAME for example.com.